# Non-linear numerical solution with variable parameter

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I have solved the following system non-linear:

```
eps = 10^-6; end = 0.2341023826;  g=0.2;
ode1 = a'[r]/r + 4 g (h'[r]^2) (1 - h[r]) == 0;
ode2 = h'[r] (a[r]/r) - (1/4)*(1/g^3) == 0; 
bcs = {h[end] == 1, a[eps] == 1};

sol = Map[First[NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, bcs}, {h, a}, r, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
Method -> {"Shooting", 
  "StartingInitialConditions" -> {h[eps] == # , a[eps] == 1}}, 
MaxSteps -> 10000]] &, {10^-6}]; 
Plot[Evaluate[{h[r], h'[r]} /. sol], {r, eps, end}, PlotLegends -> {"h", "h'"}]
Plot[Evaluate[{a[r], a'[r]} /. sol], {r, eps, end}, PlotLegends -> {"a", "a'"}]
```

[image]

This is a physical system and other two condition also must be satisfied; namely, `h[0]=0` and `a'[end]=0`. On the other hand, the value of `end` should be adjusted according to `g`. Above it is resolved to `g=0.2`so that for `end=0.2341023826` satisfies the two additional conditions with a good precision, `10^-7` order. However, I could not solve for large values of `g`. I would like at least until `g=2`.

Note: In `g=1`, for example, appear the following error message while trying to adjust the value `end`:

> "NDSolve::ndsz: At r == 1.6338560043295574`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected."

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem appears at first glance to have four boundary conditions for a second-order system of ODEs, namely, `{h[0] == 0, a[0] == 1, h[end] == 1, a'[end] == 0}`.  However, `ode1` guarantees that `a'[end] == 0` when `h[end] == 1`, reducing the number of independent boundary conditions to three.  And, since `end` can be varied, simply choose it to be the value of `r` for which `h[end] == 1`, closing the system.  These considerations can be embodied in code as

```
g = .2;
ode1 = a'[r]/r + 4 g (h'[r]^2) (1 - h[r]) == 0;
ode2 = h'[r] (a[r]/r) - (1/4)*(1/g^3) == 0; 
bcs = {h[0] == 0, a[0] == 1};

sol = First@NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, bcs, WhenEvent[h[r] > 1, end = r; "StopIntegration"]}, 
    {h, a}, {r, 0, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate[{h[r], h'[r]} /. sol], {r, 0, end}, PlotLegends -> {"h", "h'"}]
Plot[Evaluate[{a[r], a'[r]} /. sol], {r, 0, end}, PlotLegends -> {"a", "a'"}]
```

which yields `end = 0.234102`, and the plots shown in the question.  This same method works well for larger values of `g`, for instance `g = 0.4`, which yields `end = 0.584566` and the plots

[image]

[image]

Note, however, that `a[r]` dips toward zero as `r` approaches `end`.  A small amount of experimentation shows that `a[end] == 0` at approximately `g = .43135`, and both ODEs becomes singular for larger values of `g`, which accounts for the error message described in the question.  Consequently, this nonlinear system has no solutions for larger `g`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: Dear @bbgodfrey,
I have a topic already posted for some time [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180269/solution-of-nonlinear-system-with-boundary-conditions). However, I now need to solve this same problem however, this time, so that a new boundary condition is satisfied. As you have vast experience with solutions of equations differences involving boundary conditions, I would like to know if you could help of any. A colleague from this community has posted an algorithm to help, but has not yet solved the problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry to contact you this way, but I'm really in need of some help with this issue. I believe that my greatest difficulty is to find the right set of boundary conditions to enable a numerical solution.

Comment: @acsantos  I shall see what I can do, but it may not be tonight.

Comment: No problem. I await your tips when possible. Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: @acsantos  The answer by Alex Trounev seems to address well the question that you originally posted, and you accepted it.  If you have a new question, please post it separately.

Comment: So @bbgodfrey, I was in doubt if I should ask a new question, because it is the same ODE system. I will therefore make a post as a new question.

Comment: I had edited the problem to insert the new boundary condition. I undid the edit. Sorry for my mistake. I'm still getting familiar with the site.

Comment: Dear @bbgodfrey,
I have added the new question [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184522/problem-involving-a-system-of-nonlinear-coupled-odes-with-adjustable-boundary) in which a new boundary condition must now be considered as well. Any tip is welcome.

Comment: I shall look this evening.  Thanks

Comment: Okay, I'm waiting for your tips or observations.