# Solution of nonlinear system with boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear, boundary-conditions

I'm try solve the following coupled ODEs with boundary conditions:

$I. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \dfrac{4}{r}[1+A(r)]\left(\dfrac{dH}{dr}\right)^2+\dfrac{dG}{dr}=0$

$II. \ \ \ \ \dfrac{1}{r}\left(\dfrac{dA}{dr}\right)+F(r)+k^2G(r)=0$

$III. \ \ \ \ \left(\dfrac{dG}{dr}\right)^2+4k^2\left(G(r)+\dfrac{F(r)}{k^2}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{dH}{dr}\right)^2-1.6H(r)\left(\dfrac{dH}{dr}\right)^2=0$

$IV. \ \ \ \ \dfrac{d^2F}{dr^2}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{dF}{dr}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{dA}{dr}-4k^2F(r)\left(\dfrac{dH}{dr}\right)^2=0$

where $k>0$. The boundary conditions are

$H(0)=1\\A(0)=0\\G(L)=0\\F'(0)=0, \ \ F(L)=0$

with $L$ being the boundary, such that can be adjusted in order to satisfy the boundary conditions above for each value of parameter $k$ choosed. 
For this physical problem, it is desirable that the ODEs of first order obey other conditions:

$H'(0)=0, \ \ H(L)=H'(L)=0\\A'(0)=0, \ \ A'(L)=0$

Thus, from ODEs, it is possible to conclude

The ODE $I$ guarantees $G'(0)=G'(L)=0$

The ODE $II$ guarantees $F(L)=0$

I tried solve, for example, with `k=1` using the shooting method. In this case, it was only possible to execute up to $L = 1.45$ (`end=1.45`).

```
k = 1; eps = 10^-10; end = 1.45;
ode1 = 4 (h'[r] ^2) (a[r] + 1)/r == -G'[r];
ode2 = a'[r]/r == -(k^2) (G[r]) - f[r];
ode3 = (G'[r])^2 + 4 (k^2) (h'[r]^2) (G[r] + f[r]/k^2)^2 == (1.6) h[r] (h'[r]^2);
ode4 = f''[r] + f'[r]/r + (a'[r]/r) == 4 (k^2) (f[r]) ((h'[r])^2);
bcs = {h[eps] == (1 - eps), a[eps] == eps, G[end] == eps, f'[eps] == eps, f[end] == eps};

sol = NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4, bcs}, {a, h, f, G}, {r, eps, end},
Method -> {"Shooting","StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[end] == eps, G[end] == eps}}];

Plot[Evaluate[{h[r], h'[r]} /. sol[[3]]], {r, eps, end},
PlotLegends -> {"H", "H'"}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[{a[r], a'[r]} /. sol[[3]]], {r, eps, end},
PlotLegends -> {"A", "A'"}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[{G[r], G'[r]} /. sol[[3]]], {r, eps, end},
PlotLegends -> {"G", "G'"}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[Evaluate[{f[r], f'[r]} /. sol[[3]]], {r, eps, end},
PlotLegends -> {"F", "F'"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

However, for values $L>1.45$ appear the error message

> "NDSolve::ndsz: At r == 1.294087660532624`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.."

But I believe it is possible to find the correct value of $L$ that satisfies all boundary conditions. The behavior of the functions by the plots suggests that this value can be near to `2` or `3`. I can not resolve this error message for this problem.

**Added_1:** Specifically, I am interested in obtaining numerical solutions for the cases of $k=0.1$, $k=1$ and $k=2$. Then, there must be a value $L$ for each $k$ that satisfies all the boundary conditions of the problem.

Any help or altenative solution is welcome.

Comment: There can be infinitely many such parameter values L. The question is, what do you want to get, what solution?

Comment: Dear @AlexTrounev, I'm sorry if my question was unclear. I need find a value of boundary $L$ which satisfies all conditions above listed taking a particular value of $k$. In my example, assuming `k=1`, I would like to obtain a solution satisfying all the conditions. Note, however, that in my plot of the function `H[r]` the boundary condition $H(L)=0$ still is not satisfied; maybe this happening in some value near to `2` or `3`. But, I fail for values $L>1.45$.

Comment: Then, answering your question, I would like of obtain numerical solutions when `k=0.1`, `k=1` and `k=2`. For each one these cases, must have an $L$ satisfying all boundary conditions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a solution satisfying all the boundary conditions for L = 2.665. I'll show you how to build this solution. First, we solve explicitly the first and third equations for the derivatives, we have

```
ode1 = 4 (h'[r]^2) (a[r] + 1)/r == -G'[r];
ode3 = (G'[r])^2 + 
    4 (k^2) (h'[r]^2) (G[r] + f[r]/k^2)^2 == (8/5) h[r] (h'[r]^2);
s = Solve[{ode1, ode3}, {h'[r], G'[r]}] // FullSimplify
```

Here we have three pairs of roots:

```
{{Derivative[1][h][r] -> 0, 
  Derivative[1][G][r] -> 
   0}, {Derivative[1][h][r] -> -((
    I r Sqrt[5 (f[r] + k^2 G[r])^2 - 2 k^2 h[r]])/(
    2 Sqrt[5] Sqrt[k^2 (1 + a[r])^2])), 
  Derivative[1][G][r] -> (5 r (f[r] + k^2 G[r])^2 - 2 k^2 r h[r])/(
   5 k^2 (1 + a[r]))}, {Derivative[1][h][r] -> (
   I r Sqrt[5 (f[r] + k^2 G[r])^2 - 2 k^2 h[r]])/(
   2 Sqrt[5] Sqrt[k^2 (1 + a[r])^2]), 
  Derivative[1][G][r] -> (5 r (f[r] + k^2 G[r])^2 - 2 k^2 r h[r])/(
   5 k^2 (1 + a[r]))}}
```

The first pair of roots corresponds to the trivial solution $H(r)=1,G(r)=0$. On this branch the second and fourth equations become linear, and their solution can be obtained in an explicit form. We are interested in the second pair of roots, from which we will form a new system of equations:

```
ode13 = {Derivative[1][G][r] == (
    5 r (f[r] + k^2 G[r])^2 - 2 k^2 r h[r])/(5 k^2 (1 + a[r])), 
   Derivative[1][h][r] == -(( 
     r Sqrt[-5 (f[r] - k^2 G[r])^2 + 2 k^2 h[r]])/(
     2 Sqrt[5] Sqrt[k^2 (1 + a[r])^2]))};
ode24 = {a'[r]/r == -(k^2) (G[r]) - f[r], 
  f''[r] + f'[r]/r + (a'[r]/r) == 4 (k^2) (f[r]) ((h'[r])^2)};
```

We reduce this system to the dimensionless form by making a substitution `r->L*r`. Then the parameter $L$ becomes a parameter of the equations, and the system and boundary conditions have the form:

```
k = 1; eps = 10^-10; L = 1.638;
ode13 = {Derivative[1][G][r] == 
    L^2*(5 r (f[r] + k^2 G[r])^2 - 2 k^2 r h[r])/(5 k^2 (1 + a[r])), 
   Derivative[1][h][r] == -L^2*( 
     r Sqrt[-5 (f[r] + k^2 G[r])^2 + 2 k^2 h[r]])/(
     2 Sqrt[5] Sqrt[k^2 (1 + a[r])^2])};
ode24 = {a'[r]/r == -L^2*((k^2) (G[r]) - f[r]), 
    f''[r] + f'[r]/r + (a'[r]/r) == 4 (k^2) (f[r]) ((h'[r])^2)};
bcs = {h[eps] == 1, a[eps] == 0, G[1] == 0, f'[eps] == 0, f[1] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{ode13, ode24, bcs}, {a, h, f, G}, {r, eps, 1}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[eps] == -0.1, G[eps] == 0.33}}];
{Plot[Evaluate[Re[{h[r], h'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"H", "H'"}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{a[r], a'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"A", "A'"}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{G[r], G'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"G", "G'"}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{f[r], f'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"F", "F'"}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig1]

Another identity transformation of the system allows us to find a solution with L = 2:

```
k = 1; eps = 10^-10; L = 2;
ode = {G'[r] == (L^2 r (5 (f[r] + k^2 G[r])^2 - 2 k^2 h[r]))/(
    5 k^2 (1 + a[r])), 
   Derivative[1][h][r] == -((
     L^2 r Sqrt[-5 f[r]^2 - 10 k^2 f[r] G[r] - 5 k^4 G[r]^2 + 
       2 k^2 h[r]])/Sqrt[20 k^2 + 40 k^2 a[r] + 20 k^2 a[r]^2]), 
   r*f''[r] + f'[r] - (r*L^2*((k^2) (G[r]) + f[r])) == 
    r*4 (k^2) (f[r]) ((h'[r])^2), 
   a'[r] == -r*L^2*((k^2) (G[r]) + f[r])};
bcs = {h[eps] == 1, a[eps] == 0, G[1] == 0, f'[eps] == 0, f[1] == 0};

sol = NDSolve[{ode, bcs}, {a, h, f, G}, {r, eps, 1}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[eps] == -0.1, G[eps] == 0.33}}];


{Plot[Evaluate[Re[{h[r], h'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"H", "H'"}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{a[r], a'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"A", "A'"}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{G[r], G'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"G", "G'"}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{f[r], f'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"F", "F'"}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig2]

Finally, we point out a solution with `h[L]` tending to zero. In this case L = 2.665

```
k = 1; eps = 10^-10; L = 2.665;
ode = {G'[r] == (L^2 r (5 (f[r] + k^2 G[r])^2 - 2 k^2 h[r]))/(
    5 k^2 (1 + a[r])), 
   Derivative[1][h][r] == -((
     L^2 r Sqrt[-5 f[r]^2 - 10 k^2 f[r] G[r] - 5 k^4 G[r]^2 + 
       2 k^2 h[r]])/Sqrt[20 k^2 + 40 k^2 a[r] + 20 k^2 a[r]^2]), 
   r*f''[r] + f'[r] - (r*L^2*((k^2) (G[r]) + f[r])) == 
    r*4 (k^2) (f[r]) ((h'[r])^2), 
   a'[r] == -r*L^2*((k^2) (G[r]) + f[r])};
bcs = {h[eps] == 1, a[eps] == 0, G[1] == 0, f'[eps] == 0, f[1] == 0};

sol = NDSolve[{ode, bcs}, {a, h, f, G}, {r, eps, 1}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[eps] == -0.340071, 
       G[eps] == 0.736822}}];


{Plot[Evaluate[Re[{h[r], h'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"H", "H'"}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{a[r], a'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"A", "A'"}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{G[r], G'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"G", "G'"}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{f[r], f'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"F", "F'"}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig3]

We indicate the solution algorithm in the case `k = 2`. We set `A = 1`, we define two functions

```
k = 2; eps = 10^-10; L = 1;
ode = {G'[
     r] == (L^2 r (5 (f[r] + k^2 G[r])^2 - 2 k^2 h[r]))/(5 k^2 (1 + 
         a[r])), Derivative[1][h][
     r] == -((L^2 r Sqrt[-5 f[r]^2 - 10 k^2 f[r] G[r] - 
           5 k^4 G[r]^2 + 2 k^2 h[r]])/
       Sqrt[20 k^2 + 40 k^2 a[r] + 20 k^2 a[r]^2]), 
   r*f''[r] + f'[r] - (r*L^2*((k^2) (G[r]) + f[r])) == 
    r*4 (k^2) (f[r]) ((h'[r])^2), 
   a'[r] == -r*L^2*((k^2) (G[r]) + f[r])};
 bcsp = {h[eps] == 1, a[eps] == 0, f'[eps] == 0, f[eps] == p, 
   G[eps] == q};
g = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode, bcsp}, G, {r, eps, 1}, {p, q}, 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]

 F = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode, bcsp}, f, {r, eps, 1}, {p, q}, 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

To fulfill the boundary conditions for `r = 1`, we find the roots of the system of equations

```
FindRoot[{g[p, q][1] == 0, 
      F[p, q][1] == 0}, {p, -.1}, {q, .18}, Method -> "Secant"]

    Out[]= {p -> -0.118505, q -> 0.187442}
```

Using these roots we find the solution to the original system of equations

```
bcs = {h[eps] == 1, a[eps] == 0, f'[eps] == 0, 
   f[eps] == -0.1185047596657856`, G[eps] == 0.18744201629754556`};
bcs1 = {G[1] == 0, f[1] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{ode, bcs}, {a, h, f, G}, {r, eps, 1}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", "NonstiffTest" -> False}];


{Plot[Evaluate[Re[{h[r], h'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"H", "H'"}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{a[r], a'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"A", "A'"}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{G[r], G'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"G", "G'"}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Re[{f[r], f'[r]}] /. sol], {r, eps, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"F", "F'"}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig4]
If we want to additionally find `L` for which `h[1]=0`, we should move gradually changing the parameters `L,p,q`.

Comment: I have appreciated your answer. Thank you very much @AlexTrounev.

Comment: I have only one question: How did you determine the initial values for `f[eps]` and `g[eps]`? I'm asking because a small variation of these values results in an error message. Then you were very precise. How you did it?

Comment: Mathematics has a built-in algorithm that allows you to solve most problems of this type. I found these values by selection, moving from 2 to 2.665, increasing L by a small amount and using the parameters `f[eps], G[eps]` from the previous step. For this I wrote a simple code.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexTrounev, for all your help.

Comment: Dear @AlexTrounev, 
At the time of this problem, its solution up to k = 1 was sufficient. But now I also need numerical solutions for k = 2,5,10. However, the maximum I could do was for k = 1.55. For larger values of "g" the error message appears: " step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected". Any help will be welcome.

Comment: I can specify the algorithm for solving the problem. And try to study all special cases by yourself.

Comment: Great, it would help a lot. I'd be grateful. I await your algorithm. Thank you very much for your attention @AlexTrounev.

Comment: I updated the code for k = 2

Comment: Dear @AlexTrounev,
I have appreciated your hints, thank you very much. I tried to use this new algorithm. However, I could not find a value of `L` satisfying the boundary conditions, e. g. `h [1] = 0`. My best performance was obtained using the values: `L=1.383`, `p=-0.433` and `q=0.3755`. This way, results `h[1]=0.3799` which is not enough yet. When you made this new algorithm, have you been able to complete the numerical solution for `k = 2`, for example?

Comment: Should solutions be real or complex?

Comment: The solutions must be always real. It is important to point that the values mentioned in the previous message for `p` and `q` has been used in the command `FindRoot`.

Comment: Then in the initial model there is a problem related to the fact that with the growth of the parameter `k` the solutions become complex.

Comment: So, there's still another problem. For the physical system in question, I need the boundary condition `f '[1] = 0` to be satisfied as well. Now I am trying to solve at least for `k = 1` satisfying this new condition using the previous algorithm, because with this new version of its algorithm a complex solution problem is appearing.

Comment: In this case, the parameter `k` is determined from the condition `f'[1]=0`

Comment: I'm using the algorithm by you provided here for `k=1` and replacing the boundary condition `f[1]=0` by `f'[1]=0`. In this case, however, the condition `a'[1]=0` is not being satisfied as before (it is necessary). Since I have many boundary conditions, may I be using a set of unsuitable conditions?

Comment: Note: In this last comment, I meant that I need the condition `a'[1]=0` being satisfied using this new condition of `f'[1]=0`.